# Mongo database taking much more disk space than it should

Tags: mongodb

On my mongo database, I have one collection capped at 5GB, one at 10MB, and few non-capped ones. None of non-capped ones contains more than 20 small documents.

After long (4h) stress test, which only writes to 5GB capped collection, my database uses 18GBs.

This is what my db.stats says (values in MBs):

```
data-db:PRIMARY> db.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "data",
    "collections" : 9,
    "objects" : 8723395,
    "avgObjSize" : 208.8405255064112,
    "dataSize" : 1737,
    "storageSize" : 5130,
    "numExtents" : 12,
    "indexes" : 19,
    "indexSize" : 2534,
    "fileSize" : 18423,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

And this is 5GB collection stats (values in MBs):

```
data-db:PRIMARY> db.sms_message_event.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "ns" : "data.sms_message_event",
    "count" : 8723300,
    "size" : 1737,
    "avgObjSize" : 0.00019912189194456226,
    "storageSize" : 5120,
    "numExtents" : 3,
    "nindexes" : 6,
    "lastExtentSize" : 1026,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 2534,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 395,
        "t_1_when_-1" : 475,
        "smsc_message_id_1" : 185,
        "user_id_1_t_1_when_1" : 481,
        "message_id_1" : 318,
        "virtual_number_recipient_when_index" : 678
    },
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : 2147483647,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So why is fileSize so much bigger than storageSize? I can't even run repairDatabase() now, but I tried compact() on each non-capped collection, with no result. Actually, this was expected as db was clean before the stress test. I mean files were deleted, not only collections dropped.

From logs I can see additional data files were created during stress test, in ~1h intervals.

Some logs: http://pastie.org/private/t8u9caxstafbjdybgwtsfw

UPDATE: After another night, and another pass of 4h stress tests, it's 28GBs :(

```
data-db:PRIMARY> db.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "data",
    "collections" : 9,
    "objects" : 8724995,
    "avgObjSize" : 208.840894006243,
    "dataSize" : 1737,
    "storageSize" : 5130,
    "numExtents" : 12,
    "indexes" : 19,
    "indexSize" : 2590,
    "fileSize" : 28658,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: That is how mongoDB works... it preallocates data files to a particular size.  You can read more about it here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/

Comment: If this is a small database you might want to use `smallfiles` which uses a much smaller default data file size.... http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#smallfiles

Comment: Well but I understood it preallocates one file in advance. The maximum allocated file size is 2GB. Our data has 5GB - see `storageSize` (inserts only, no removals, as this is a capped collection). How come the total went to 18GB?

Comment: you can also use --noprealloc with --smallfiles or without.  These are well documented and frequently asked about here.

Comment: We know about --noprealloc, and --smallfiles, and we read some documentation on mongo sites and here on SO. Still, we don't know why it takes 18GBs, when it needs less than 10. Even with 2GBs overhead, it's still quite much less than 18.

Comment: I will back you up there, 18GBs is stupid, I never witness this kind of space wastage on my databases. The only thing I could of thought was fragmentation of data outside of your own control. I am interested though, how come you can run a cmpaact but not a repairDatabase? compact does essentially the same but on a single collection? I would highly recommend you get a envo where you can run repairdatabase, even if it is locally on another computer. I would be interested to see the results.

Comment: I run compact on another collections. You can't compact capped collection anyway. Maybe repairDatabase() doesn't check if some collection is capped, but just reports not enough disk space when it detects your DB is larger than free space.

Comment: `Compact` and `Repair` are *not* the essentially the same. Repairing the database recreates the data files and indexes, and will reduce actual disk space usage. The compact command will rewrite and defragment a single collection, but does not free up any physical disk space. A repair will rewrite the files from scratch (similar to resyncing a secondary node completely) and will reclaim space on-disk but will require up to 2* the disk space to complete. What did `db.stats()` report before the stress test? Are you using MMS?

Comment: I'm not sure what db.stats() reported before the stress test, but definitely the DB wasn't that big. As I can see from logs, shortly after db files were deleted and system was started, it created 3 2GB datafiles. Then during stress test it created another 6 2GB datafiles. Strange that it was in 3 "batches", 2 files in each. I mean 2 files were created at the same time, then after ~1h another two files, then after another ~1h next 2 files.

Comment: @MarkHillick Aha yea forgot that, nice catch.

Comment: @amorfis can you post the (sanitised) logs to gist/pastie etc?

Comment: @MarkHillick Added link to pastie with some logs

Comment: @amorfis that just looks like standard pre-allocation of files that `mongod` performs.

Comment: Today, after another 4h stress test, it is 28 GBs :(

Comment: Can you pastie the code for what your stress test actually does?  A capped collection is preallocated and doesn't grow, so the extra space must be coming from index allocations or other collections in the same database.  It would be helpful if you can pastie the stats for the other 8 collections in the same database so there is a complete picture.

Comment: The code for stress test is far too complicated to paste here. Mongo writes are just small part of it. I upgraded mongo to 2.4.3 today, and I managed to shrink filesize using replica set. I shut down one node, deleted files, start it up againg. It recreated the data, and consumed "only" 10 GBs. I did it for 2 nodes, leaving only one, secondary, as it was. Will see tomorrow what happens to it during stress test.

Comment: @amorfis: if you can't post any code for the stress test, stats for the other collections in the same database would still be helpful. Otherwise there isn't much information to go on aside from you running a stress test that grows your database (which might be expected, depending on how you have constructed your stress test).  You do appear to have five additional indexes on your capped collection, so it would also be worth running your stress test with just the default `_id` index to see if index changes are related to your unanticipated disk space usage.

Comment: Ok, so yesterday I updated mongo 2.2.1 -> 2.4.3. So stress tests were run on 2.4.3. It now uses 16GBs on primary node and one secondary (the one that was cleaned), and 30GBs on another secondary (the one that was not cleaned, and used 28GBs before last stress test). All the stats, made from primary node, are here: http://pastie.org/private/ld61i28cnzcaew9bfrd7dw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of a bug in MongoDB when re-using space allocated for capped collections.   It's been filed as [SERVER-9489](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9489) and will be triaged and hopefully fixed soon.

The way you can continue running your stress tests without running out of disk space is by deleting the test DB directory after the test finishes, and then creating a new one when you run the new test (this assumes you don't need to reuse the same data).  If you do need the same data you can use mongodump to preserve it from run to run though there may be other simpler options that depend on your exact usage.

Comment: alternatively, you can put your capped collection in a separate DB and dropDatabase and recreate it between runs - that will release all space.

Comment: Thank you. Another option is to stop mongod on secondary nodes, delete the files, and then start it again. It's in replSet, so that's a way to go when it hits us on production. I hope however that it's going to be fixed earlier.